# In a cube of nominal size $5$ inches, the uncertainty in the measurement of each side is $10\%.$ Find the uncertainty in the measurement of the volume

Tags: solution-verification, numerical-methods, approximation, standard-error

In the calculation of the volume of a cube of nominal size $5$ inches, the uncertainty in the measurement of each side is $10\%.$ Find the uncertainty in the measurement of the volume.

I tried solving the problem as follows:

Given, the nominal size of the cube is $5$ inches. So, if the side length of the cube is $a$ then, $a\approx 5$ inches. Now, the uncertainty in measurement of each side is $10%$ i.e $5\times 10\%=0.5$ inches. Thus, the measured side length of the cube ,  is $a\pm 0.5$ and the maximum length of the cube possible, is $5+0.5=5.5$inches. So, the maximum volume is, $5.5^3=166.375$ .

Now, the nominal volume is, $a^3=5^3=125$ and the maximum absolute error possible in the measurement of volume, is $166.375-125=41.375$ due to which, the relative error in the measurement of volume, is $41.375/125=0.331$. Now, the percentage error is indeed, $0.331\times 100=33.1$. The uncertainty in the measurement of volume is actually the percentage error, so the uncertainty in volume is $33.1\%$ as well.

---

However, the answer given is $30%.$ I am not sure whether I made a mistake.

The probability of me making a mistake is possible because, I just felt that calculating the uncertainty in volume, means calculating the percentage error in the measurement of volume. I made this conclusion just intuitively.

Next, while calculating the percentage error I needed to calculate the relative error. To calculate the relative error, I needed to calculate the absolute error and to find the absolute error I needed the measured volume. But then, I just felt that I should take the measured volume to be the maximum possible volume. That is the reason why, I chose the measured side length of tge cube to $5.5$ inches to obtain the maximum possible volume. But all these things, I did was just me following my intuitions.

I don't really understand whether  all these steps are justified in here.

Comment: The absolute error in the edge length is $0.5$". Since $4.5^3=91.125$ and $5.5^3=166.375$, the maximum absolute error in volume is $41.375$, which is $33.1\%$ of $125$. So I get the same answer.

Comment: @robjohn But if my approach is correct, it would be helpful if you post why do you think my method is jusified. Thanks for confirming the answer!

Comment: Perhaps they are assuming $10\%$ is given to one significant digit, so the error will be known to one significant digit; thus, $33.1\%$ becomes $30\%$. Otherwise, the book seems to be wrong.

Comment: There's a well-known rule: when multiplying, add the relative errors. So to get the relative error in the volume of a cube, you triple the relative error of the side. This rule is just an approximation. But it relates to calculus: $(x+dx)(y+dy)=(xy+ydx+xdy)$

Comment: If this is for a calculus class, they may expect you to find it with $dV=3x^2dx$.

Comment: Usually one assumes that in multiplication relativ errors ad up since you have l*l*l the errors ad up to 30%, but this is just the usual way which you learned maybe and it comes from the usual role  to calculate errors. The question was not the maximal error, which you did right.

Comment: @JohnDouma No, this is for a class on Numerical Mathematical Analysis  in a Mathematics Honours Course.

Comment: @Thomas I would expect that calculus is a prerequisite for such a course. At least, you should be familiar with differentiation and basic properties of limits.

Comment: @PM2Ring And I am :)

Comment: 10% is an extremal case for the approximation $(1+a)^3\approx 1+3a$, giving, as seen, a "visible" difference. This approximation works much better for errors of 1% or less. Then the error in the error bound will not be that significant.